# how to compare radio button values with textbox values in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

i have four radio buttons and one text box..i have to check the selected radio button value equals to the textbox value.. anyone plz help me

Comment: You will have to give us a little bit more to work with than that...

Answer (score 2):

```
if(radioButtonList.SelectedValue == textBox1.Text.Trim())
{
   //your code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

textBox does not contain a Value property.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue) &&
                RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue.Equals(TextBox1.Text, StringComparison.Ordinal))
    {
        //your code goes here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well.You didn't clarify where you want to do this comparison i.e. ClientSide or ServerSide.If you want it server side you can prefer earlier posted answers otherwise for client side try this one using Jquery.

```
<div>
    <input type='radio' name='rd' value='A'>
    <input type='radio' name='rd' value='B'>
    <input type='radio' name='rd' value='C'>
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("input:radio[name='rd']").click(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked"))
        {
            if($.trim($(this).val()) == $.trim($("#txtName").val()))
                alert("Yeah!I got matched value.");
            else
                alert("Oops!Not matched.");
        }
    });

    });
</script>
```

Click on this link:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wJ6aH/)**